Convert string range into array of numbers in perl and prefix with another string
I have a string list (i.e: 1-15) and I want to generate this
Scenario_01 ... Scenario_10 Scenario_11 ... Scenario_15

I tried this
range=1-15
echo $range | perl -pe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/join(" Scenario_0",$1..$2)/eg'

and getting this
1 Scenario_02 Scenario_03 Scenario_04 Scenario_05 Scenario_06 Scenario_07 Scenario_08 Scenario_09 Scenario_010 Scenario_011 Scenario_012 Scenario_013 Scenario_014 Scenario_015


Use sprintf() to print a number with a given number of digits and leading zeroes.

You're simply adding 0 before the number, regardless of whether it already has 2 digits.

how do I overcome the numbers greater >= 10?

I just told you, and I also provided a link to another question that shows it in detail. What more do I have to do?

why is the first number printed with the prefix?

That's how join works, it prints the first element, the separator, the second element, the separator, and so on up to the separator and the last element.

Because join() puts the delimiter Scenario_0 between each number.

understood. thank you for the help and feedback :)

(bash) printf "Scenarios_%02d\n" {1..15}; this will print each entry on a separate line; to print them all on the same line replace \n with a single space though this will leave a trailing space at the end of the line

Simpler bash: echo Scenario_{01..15} (Do have to know the range in advance as bracket expansion doesn't work with variables in the range)

Brace expansion is great, but not easily usable if the range is coming from input...

Use sprintf to format the numbers.
echo 1-15 | perl -pe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/join " ", map { sprintf "Scenario_%02d", $_ }  $1 .. $2/e'

%02d works for 00 .. 99. If you want 000 .. 999, use %03d, etc.

perfect. just what I needed

Using echo might not be the best solution there.

@TLP: I just used the same way as the question.

@choroba what if I only have a single digit number and not a range? but I want the same results?

Create a new question to ask a new question.
